# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have faced the "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" issue while run the android app source in eclipse.

So i have installed the JAVA 8 update 221 and changed jre1.8.0_221 as default. Then set compiler compliance level to 1.8. But while run the application i have faced the issue like "Your project contains error"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the used run configuration. Most likely it overrides the JRE and uses the Java 1.7 JRE for running the app.

Comment: Eclipse support for android was dropped like 5 years ago. Time to move on

Comment: I have changed to JRE 1.7 but it's not work out.

Comment: If this is an error thrown at *runtime*, you're not running *your* application with a new enough version of Java.